# I cannot post a tweet using twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm trying to post a tweet using twitter4j and when I call the .updateStatus method it stops and gives me an error. This is all of my code: (I do have the keys/access tokens in my actual code)

```
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey("")
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret("")
            .setOAuthAccessToken("")
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("");
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
    try
    {
        Status status = twitter.updateStatus("hi");
    }
    catch(TwitterException f){
        f.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, what's the error ?

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: Hi! Sorry the error is TwitterException{exceptionCode=[2fc5b7cb-1051ec12 2fc5b7cb-1051ebe8], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.7} Input File Object

Comment: It also says connection reset if that helps